# How does the Prism rune for Diamond Skin interact with spells that have a continious cost?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

[Diamond Skin (Prism)](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/diamond-skin/d)

[Ray of Frost](http://d3db.com/skill/i/ray-of-frost)

If you had Diamond Skin active with Prism, how does that affect the upkeep cost of channelling Ray of Frost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channeled spells use up the listed AP cost per "tick". The amount of time each "tick" takes depends on your weapon speed.

So in this case, each "tick" will cost 13 AP (7 less than normal).

Comment: Can you cite a source?

Comment: @hkf - This is what I've picked up from a number of forum discussions, but I don't have any good links on hand. I'll try to find an authoritative source.